# PHP loop for printing MYSQLi array not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

so what's happening is that i am printing 4 rows from my mysql db into a div, and then closing that div, and then creating a new div and then printing 4 rows and then ending that div. And so on and so forth, until there is no longer any content in my database.

Now after this is done, it will print a form where the user can add to the DB (riht after the last name is printed) (also if there is already 4 names in a div, then it will have to create another div)
The code below is what i currently have, and it works, however it has some issues.
The issues are:
- The first entry of the DB isn't printed, it starts printing from the 2nd entry.
- At the end of printing all the names it prints the content `div` but with no names in it. (1 or 2 of them)
- The form won't create another div for the form if there is already 4 names in a div

By fiddling with the `$count2` variable i can get it to get rid of those empty content divs, however then i lose function on my submit button (it's there, but you can't click it)

Can anyone spot and correct where the issues are?

Thanks a lot guys!

P.S I commented as best as i could so you could understand what i think should be going on.

```
$countsql = <<<SQL
            SELECT *
            FROM `deathnote`
SQL;

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $countsql)) {

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    $countresult = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
}
$count2=0; //count how many overall names have been printed
$pagecount=0; //count for how many names are on a page
while($result->fetch_assoc() != NULL){ //While result isn't empty
 echo '<div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);">'; //start new page div
    while ($pagecount < 4) { //loop to put only 4 names on 1 page
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //grab name and cod
                echo '<div class="content"><div class="name">'  . $row['victim'] . '</div><div class="cod">'  . $row['cod'] . '</div></div>'; //display name and cod inside a content div
        $pagecount++; //increase the count of amount of names on page
        $count2++; //increase the overall names printed
        if ($count2 == $countresult) { //if the overall names printed = the total count of whats in the database (meaning there is nothing left to print)
        echo '<div class="content"><form action="write.php" method="post"><div class="name">Name: <br/> Cause Of Death: </div><div class="cod"><textarea type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" placeholder="Input Name" required></textarea> <br /> <textarea type="text" name="cod" maxlength="130" rows="4" placeholder="Cause of Death" required></textarea> <br /><input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit"></div></form></div>'; //print the form for user to add to the database
        }

    }
$pagecount=0; //because there is 4 names printed, we have to set the count back to 0
echo '</div>'; //end the 'page' div (which will end the page)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, database records should be outputted in groups of four records until there are no more records.

It might be easier to fetch your database content into an array and then iterate through the array.

However, here's a similar method to the code you provided above.
The code is commented in an attempt to explain what's going on.

```
// initialize record counter
$count=0;

// loop through query result
while($row->fetch_assoc($stmt)){

    // increment record counter
    $count++;

    // if this is the first record in this group, start a new page div
    if ($count==1) {
      ?><div style="background-image:url(images/paper.jpg);"><?php
    }

    //display name and cod inside a content div
    ?><div class="content">
      <div class="name"><?=$row['victim']?></div>
      <div class="cod"><?=$row['cod']?></div>
    </div><?php

    // if this is fourth record in group, close page div and reset counter
    if ($count==4) {
      ?></div><?php
      $count=0;
    }

}

// if the last group had less than four items, close final page div.
if ($count>0) {
  ?></div><?php
}

//print the form for user to add to the database
?><div class="content">
    <form action="write.php" method="post">
        <div class="name">
            Name:<br/>
            Cause Of Death:
        </div>
        <div class="cod">
            <textarea type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" placeholder="Input Name" required></textarea><br />
            <textarea type="text" name="cod" maxlength="130" rows="4" placeholder="Cause of Death" required></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### Your Issues:

**1. The first entry of the DB isn't printed, it starts printing from the 2nd entry.**

- This is because you have two nested "fetch" loops. You only need one.

**2. At the end of printing all the names it prints the content div but with no names in it.**

- This is because you've got a "page count" loop inside your "fetch" loop.
   So, even on the last record, it still outputs four content boxes.

**3. The form won't create another div for the form if there is already 4 names in a div.**

- This is because your form output is dependent on the last group containing four items.